# What is the recommended way to do embeddings in jax?

Tags: jax

So I mean something where you have a categorical feature $X$ (suppose you have turned it into ints already) and say you want to embed that in some dimension using the features $A$ where $A$ is arity x n_embed.

What is the usual way to do this? Is using a for loop and vmap correct? I do not want something like `jax.nn`, something more efficient like

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding

For example consider high arity and low embedding dim.

Is it `jnp.take` as in the flax.linen implementation here? https://github.com/google/flax/blob/main/flax/linen/linear.py#L624

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with `using a for loop and vmap` ?

Comment: @GeoffreyNegiar I just meant instead of using jnp.take you would literally iterate over the indices. But I now think take is the correct way, it looks like that is what various libaries using jax are doing in their implementations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed the typical way to do this in pure jax is with `jnp.take`.  Given array `A` of embeddings of shape `(num_embeddings, num_features)` and categorical feature `x` of integers shaped `(n,)` then the following gives you the embedding lookup.

```py
jnp.take(A, x, axis=0)  # shape: (n, num_features)
```

If using Flax then the recommended way would be to use the [`flax.linen.Embed`](https://flax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/_autosummary/flax.linen.Embed.html) module and would achieve the same effect:

```py
import flax.linen as nn

class Model(nn.Module): 
  @nn.compact
  def __call__(self, x):
    emb = nn.Embed(num_embeddings, num_features)(x)  # shape
```

Comment: `A[x]` works too

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that `A` is the embedding table and `x` is any shape of indices.

1. `A[x]`, which is like `jnp.take(A, x, axis=0)` but simpler.
2. `vmap`-ed `A[x]`, which parallelizes along axis 0 of `x`.
3. nested `vmap`-ed `A[x]`, which parallelizes along all axes of `x`.

Here are the source code for your reference.

```py
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

embs = jnp.array([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]], dtype=jnp.float32)

x = jnp.array([[3, 1], [2, 0]], dtype=jnp.int32)

print("\ntake\n", jnp.take(embs, x, axis=0))
print("\nuse []\n", embs[x])
print(
    "\nvmap\n",
    jax.vmap(lambda embs, x: embs[x], in_axes=[None, 0], out_axes=0)(embs, x),
)

print(
    "\nnested vmap\n",
    jax.vmap(
        jax.vmap(lambda embs, x: embs[x], in_axes=[None, 0], out_axes=0),
        in_axes=[None, 0],
        out_axes=0,
    )(embs, x),
)
```

BTW, I learned the nested-vmap trick from [the IREE GPT2 model code](https://github.com/iree-org/iree-jax/blob/26006ef5842a604e28ea71e65e9224ad20f028e9/models/gpt2/model.py#L143-L146) by James Bradbury.